# How to create a HTML table using *ngFor?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ngfor

Given the following arrays that have the same size:

**Compnent.ts**

```
studentName=['Jhon',Johanne','Nadia'];
studentAge=[16,15,16];
studentScore=[10,7,9];
```

NB: These tables have always the same size but their size increases or decreases depending on the data on the ag-grid. I put this example to simplify.

**compnent.html**

```
<ng-template #studentInformationTemplate>
...
<div class= "table">
   <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th> Student Name </th>
               <th> Student Age  </th>
               <th> Student Score </th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor= "let name of studentName"
               <td> {{ name }} </td>
           </tr>
           <tr *ngFor= "let age of studentAge"
               <td> {{ age}} </td>
           </tr>
           <tr *ngFor= "let score of studentScore"
               <td> {{ score}} </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
...
</ng-template>
```

**Given Output**

[image: Given Output]

**Expected output (The values of each array in one column)**
[image: Expected output]

Comment: You should combine all the items into objects as items of a single array

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you precise more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat over all the student names and then use the index to grab each position from their corresponding arrays. As @Daniel pointed out in the comments though this would be much easier if you had a single array with all the data in it.

```
  ...
       <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor= "let name of studentName; index as i">
               <td>{{ studentName[i] }}</td>
               <td>{{ studentAge[i] }}</td>
               <td>{{ studentScore[i] }}</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   ...
```

Comment: This one put all the values in the same row

Comment: I misunderstood sorry, updated the answer.